# A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 352, 640, 64), (1, 352, 640, 64)]

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to pre-process an image from an intermediate layer in an UNet. I'm getting the following error when trying to concatenate. I tried reshaping the tensor but it cannot be converted from (1, 352, 640, 64) to (None, 352, 640, 64). Even the layers None value cannot be changed. How to resolve this issue? I need to change 1 to None or wise-versa such that the both shapes are similar.

`ValueError: A Concatenate layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 352, 640, 64), (1, 352, 640, 64)]`

```
def unet(pretrained_weights = None,input_size = (352,640,3)):
    inputs = Input(input_size)

    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)

    pool1 = RA_unit(x=pool1,h=pool1.shape[1].value, w=pool1.shape[2].value,n=16)

    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)

    # pool2 = RA_unit(x=pool2,n=16)

    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)

    # pool3 = RA_unit(x=pool3,n=16)

    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv4)
    drop4 = Dropout(0.5)(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(drop4)

    # pool4 = RA_unit(x=pool4,n=16)

    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv5)
    drop5 = Dropout(0.5)(conv5)

    up6 = Conv2D(512, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(drop5))
    merge6 = concatenate([drop4,up6], axis = 3)

    # merge6 = RA_unit(x=merge6,n=16)

    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv6)

    up7 = Conv2D(256, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv6))
    merge7 = concatenate([conv3,up7], axis = 3)

    # merge7 = RA_unit(x=merge7,n=16)

    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv7)

    up8 = Conv2D(128, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv7))
    merge8 = concatenate([conv2,up8], axis = 3)

    # merge8 = RA_unit(x=merge8,n=16)

    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv8)

    up9 = Conv2D(64, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv8))
    merge9 = concatenate([conv1,up9], axis = 3)

    # merge9 = RA_unit(x=merge9,n=16)

    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(2, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)

    conv10 = Conv2D(3, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')(conv9)

    model = Model(input = inputs, output = conv10)

    model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-4), loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy']) # original 1e-4 | 2e-4 = 0.00020

    model.summary()

    if(pretrained_weights):
        model.load_weights(pretrained_weights)

    return model

def RA_unit(x, h, w, n):
    x_1 = tf.nn.avg_pool(x, ksize=[1, h/n, 2, 1], strides=[1, h/n, 2, 1], padding="SAME")
    x_t = tf.zeros([1, h, w, 0], tf.float32)
    for k in range(n):
        x_t_1 = tf.slice(x_1, [0,k,0,0], [1,1,int(w/2),x.shape[3].value])
        x_t_2 = tf.image.resize_images(x_t_1, [h,w], 1)
        x_t_3 = tf.abs(x - x_t_2)
        x_t = tf.concat([x_t, x_t_3], axis=3)
    x_out = tf.concat([x, x_t], axis=3)
    return x_out

def RA_unit_new(x, h, w, n):
    x_1 = tf.nn.avg_pool(x, ksize=[1, h/n, 2, 1], strides=[1, h/n, 2, 1], padding="SAME")
    x_t = tf.zeros([1, h, w, 0], tf.float32)
    for k in range(n):
        x_t_1 = tf.slice(x_1, [0,k,0,0], [1,1,int(w/2),x.shape[3].value])
        x_t_2 = tf.image.resize_images(x_t_1, [h,w], 1)
        x_t_3 = tf.abs(x - x_t_2)
        x_t = tf.concat([x_t, x_t_3], axis=3)
    x_out = tf.concat([x, x_t], axis=3)
    conv = Conv2D(x.shape[3], 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(x_out)
    return conv
```

Comment: Could you please point out which concatenation is causing your issue and which variable has shape `(None, 352, 640, 64)` versus  `(1, 352, 640, 64)`? Thanks!

Comment: pool1 after max pooling produces the shape `(None, 352, 640, 64)` and pool1 which is obtained through RA_unit is of shape `(1, 352, 640, 64)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're clear what the problem is. When concatenating, only the dimension you're concatenating on can be different.

So you have to make your `batch_size=1`. To do that, set your input layer as follows.

```
input_size=(1,352,640,3)
inputs = Input(batch_shape=input_size)
```

The other option is to make sure your `RA_Unit` more general and get it to process a batch of inputs and return a `(None, x, y, z)` type tensor. Instead of something that can process only a single input (i.e. batch_size=1).

Comment: How to create a tensor with None values? I mean this (None, x, y, z)

Comment: You'd have to make sure that you are keeping the `batch_dimension` as it is and performing transformations on other dimensions. So that the `batch` dimension stays in tact. But it depends, you'd have to see for yourself if this is a possibility for your `RA_unit` transformer.

Comment: I changed it as follows inputs = Input(batch_shape=input_size) and changed the RA_unit to return a shape similar as the input. But now there is a different problem. `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'Dimension', please use // instead`. I added the new RAU unit as RA_unit_new in the above question.